# sh: line 1: Forbidden!: command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I was trying to install **REX-Ray** inside AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu) by executing this request :

```
curl -sSL https://dl.bintray.com/emccode/rexray/install | sh -
```

Artical : https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.2/

After I ran this request, I got this error :

> sh: line 1: **Forbidden**!: command not found

I have not experienced this kind of error before, what causes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In case any one run into this issue here is what I did when I had same issues seems the URL for rexray changed:

```
curl -sSL https://rexray.io/install | sh -s -- stable 0.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to display output of `curl -sSL https://dl.bintray.com/emccode/rexray/install`. Indeed, it return `Forbidden!`. Obviously, this command does not exist.

There is probably an error in https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.2/

Comment: if so, how do i install this? Rex-ray documentation  says to install this by ruuning this command. https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.2/

Comment: It's some kind of problem at that site, it's not working as it should. You should contact the maintainers and let them know that the instructions don't work.

Comment: thanks for the support. I will contact them and let u know here. also I will mark this as correct answer